# 「rescue500 => SocketError : getaddrinfo: Name or service not known」 cannot be resolved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

### Want to achieve

ruby 2.6.5
Rails 6.0.4
Amazon AWS S3
Thankyou for watching.
I am creating an application in Rails.
I want to upload an image to AWS S3, but I get the following error in the log and cannot upload it

```
rescue500 => SocketError : getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
/home/ec2-user/test_app/web/app/services/clamav_service.rb:4:in `initialize'
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.x.s3.local = false
config.x.s3.region = ENV["AWS_S3_REGION"]
config.x.s3.bucket = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]
config.x.s3.access_key = ENV["AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY"]
config.x.s3.secret_access_key = ENV["AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
config.x.s3.password = ENV["AWS_S3_PASSWORD"]
config.x.s3.path = ENV["AWS_S3_PATH"]
```

Environment variables in ec2

```
AWS_S3_REGION=ap-northeast-1                                                                                                                                                          
AWS_S3_BUCKET=xxx                                                                                                                                                   
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY=yyy                                                                                                                                                
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=zzz                                                                                                                     
AWS_S3_PASSWORD=                                                                                                                                                                      
AWS_S3_PATH=uploads/
```

We have made the following settings.
I have confirmed that AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are correct.
In my local environment, I was able to upload successfully, so I think it is a bug in my environment.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me if I missed anything.

Comment: Are you sure all `ENV['...']` are typed correctly and have the correct values? The error can be only from there.

Comment: What do you do in `clamav_service.rb:4:in `initialize'` ?

Comment: Update with `services/clamav_service.rb:4` to see the code. Ideally you can debug in your rails console, call that line .

Answer (score 0):

clamd doesn't expand environment variables, so I had to write them directly.